# How to fix "non-static vs static" issue in onCreate() as an input receiver

Tags: java, android

So I have made a simple app that currently has an EditText input with a button that, onClick, takes user to a specified website + the user input at the end.

However, my EditText input doesn't seem to "connect" with my declared String and therefore no input value gets detected, taking the user straight to the default website as the button is pressed.

I have tried this code:

```
rns = et.getText().toString();
```

Where "et" is the declared name of the EditText input, and "rns" is the declared name of the String to read the input.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText et;
    String rns; /* Declarations here */
    Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regNum); /* regNum is android id */
        rns = EditText.getText().toString(); /* This is the line in question, 
with a red underscore on "getText() due to being referenced from a static context */
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regBut); /* regBut is android id */
        b.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        if (v == b){
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse
("https://www.vegvesen.no/kjoretoy/Kjop+og+salg/Kjøretøyopplysninger?
registreringsnummer=" + rns));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    }
```

I expected the EditText input field "et" (id = regNum) to detect the user input, but it doesn't at all. One thing I hadn't considered was it not detecting numbers, but I checked and it didn't detect letters alone either.

(Test results were all with the aforementioned code:

```
rns = et.getText().toString();
```

)

Comment: why would you expect there to be **user input** in `onCreate` ?  Sure the screen has not even displayed at this stage?

Comment: Your question and your question title don't match

Comment: @Scary Wombat I thought the following code registered input: «rns = EditText.getText().toString();» because of the String and EditText being connected in a way. I’m a beginner in this and struggle with even basic code, so I was hoping for an explanation based of my title question, but the question itself in the main body of my post ended up just explaining and straying away from the question, I apologize for that

Comment: why did you think that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should have been:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText et;
    String rns; /* Declarations here */
    Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regNum); /* regNum is android id */

        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regBut); /* regBut is android id */
        b.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        if (v == b){
            /* Get the string from the edittext on button press */
            rns = et.getText().toString();
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse
("https://www.vegvesen.no/kjoretoy/Kjop+og+salg/Kjøretøyopplysninger?registreringsnummer=" + rns));
           startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You retrieve your EditText via `et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regNum);`, so you should retrieve it using the `et` variable you just declared:

`et.getText().toString()`

You are accessing the method directly from class name, (not on the instance of your object) and calling getText() from it, to which in my recollection is not a static method.

Also have you tried checking against the view id on your onClick callback? v == b is not always true in this case.

Try

```
public void onClick(View v){
    if (v.getId() == R.id.regBut){
        ...
    }
}
```

You can also check out JakeWharton's [ButterKnife](https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) for injecting views from xml to your code. So you won't have to do `findViewById()` and you can annotate `@OnClick` to your respective methods.

Comment: still trying to access the value in `onCreate` seems wrong